# check roles in js file to enable or disable menu items

Tags: javascript, jsp, dojo

I have a java.util.List in jsp page which contains pageIds. Each page is mapped to pageId and based on pageId user has access to view the page else the page should be hidden so that user should not see that page name in the dropdown menu. How can i achieve this, please suggest.Below is the code:

jsp code:

```
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/menu.js"></script>
//code
        java.util.ArrayList<Integer> accessList = (java.util.ArrayList<Integer>) session.getAttribute("AccessList");
    //accessList has pageId's
```

How can i check in menu.js whether the user logged in has access to the page.Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Security stuff should be server-side, so rather than giving all users the widgets and disabling client-side with JS, check server-side and don't even give them the widgets if they aren't logged in.  Remember, modern browsers include developer tools that allow user to easily edit the HTML/Javascript of your page, meaning JS security is no security.